# Get key from value in multidimentionnal array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of 1500 english synonyms formatted as follows:

```
array(1521) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "April"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Apr"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "China"
    [1]=>
    string(26) "People's Republic of China"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "mainland China"
    [3]=>
    string(15) "Communist China"
    [4]=>
    string(9) "Red China"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "PRC"
    [6]=>
    string(6) "Cathay"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "December"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Dec"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Earth"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "earth"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "world"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "globe"
  }

  ...

  [1519]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "year"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "solar year"
  }
  [1520]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "zero"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "null"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make a function which takes a word and returns the sub-array key

Ex:

```
$result = get_synonym_family($array, "world");
echo $result; //3
```

I tried to combine some of the examples I found on the already existing stackoverflow questions but nothing was fitting my needs

Comment: `foreach` + `array_search`

Comment: @u_mulder, I think that `foreach` + `in_array` :)

Comment: @Dekel really? `in_array` will return `3`?

Comment: the `return` should be in the `foreach`. the `3` is in the 1st level (not the second).

Comment: @u_mulder, you can check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `foreach` function to walk-over all the values in the array, and then use the `in_array` function to check if the value exists in the inner-array:

```
function get_synonym_family($array, $word) {
    foreach($array as $key => $sub_array) {
        if (in_array($word, $sub_array)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = [1 => ['apple','ball'.'cat'],2 => ['foo'.'bar']];

function get_synonym_family($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       foreach($val as $a)
       {
          if($a == $id)
          {
              return $key;
          }
       }

   }
   return null;
}

echo searchForId('apple',$array);
```